# Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following code:

```
nonstopfreq :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,Int)] -> [(a,Int)]
nonstopfreq (x : xs) (y : ys) = nonstopfreq xs (filter (\y -> not (x == fst y)) ys)
```

where the arguments are:

1. list of `String`.
2. tuple `[([String],Int)]`

but I get the following error, because?

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
Expected type: [(String, Int)]
  Actual type: [([String], Int)]
In the second argument of `nonstopfreq', namely `aPrimerB'
In the expression: nonstopfreq lStopWords aPrimerB
In an equation for `aSegon':
    aSegon = nonstopfreq lStopWords aPrimerB
```

What I am trying to eliminate the elements listed and the tuple.

`AprimerB` is: `[(["the"],1818),(["and"],940),(["to"],809),(["a"],690),(["of"],631),(["it"],545)‌​,(["she"],542),(["said"],462),(["you"],435),(["in"],431)]`. 
The other argument, `lStopWords`, has type as obtained from `words`:

```
   do
     ...
     stopWords <- hGetContents fileStopWords
     let lStopWords = words stopWords
```

What I try is to remove `AprimerB` items shown in `LstopWords`.

Comment: What is this function trying to do? It looks like there are multiple problems with it.

Comment: can you please post the input that you are using?

Comment: You have two different `y` variables here -- one in the initial function pattern match, and one in the lambda.

Comment: The arguments don't match the type signature (if you substitute a with String, the second argument should be `[(String,Int)]`).

Comment: The type error is due to the definition of `aPrimerB`, which is not in the posted code. (The posted function does have other problems, though).

Comment: AprimerB is style:
     [(["the"],1818),(["and"],940),(["to"],809),(["a"],690),(["of"],631),(["it"],545),(["she"],542),(["said"],462),(["you"],435),(["in"],431)] 

And lStopWords is type words.

What I try is to remove AprimerB items shown in LstopWords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that `lStopWords` is simply a list of strings (of words, in this particular case) – i.e., `[a] ~ [String]` or `a ~ String`. That means the second argument with its general type `[(a, Int)]` becomes `[(String, Int)]`. However, you've passed

```
aPrimerB = [(["the"],1818), (["and"],940) ... ]
```

where each of the strings is contained in a singleton list. So the type of this is `[([String], Int)]`. Since each list has just one argument, you can actually change it easily to

```
aPrimerB :: [(String, Int)]
aPrimerB = [("the",1818), ("and",940) ... ]
```

which will get rid of that error.

Alternatively, you can also wrap every element of the words list in another singleton-list layer.

```
   let lStopWords :: [[String]]
       lStopWords = map (:[]) $ words stopWords
```

Then you can keep the old definition of `aPrimerB`, because now `a ~ [String]`. The result would be basically the same, but the singleton lists seem pretty useless here.

---

Note that even with that error fixed, `nonstopfreq` will still not work: there is no base case, so it will crash when either of the lists is empty.

Comment: okey, I walk aPrimerB and the first element use the function unwords?

Comment: @MercedesCabreraTorres: you _could_ automatically transform it with `map (first unwords)`, yes. But why is that even necessary – couldn't you just define `aPrimerB` with the right type to begin with?